# Spark clustering - one RDD multiple clusters, optimal cluster size, controlling set sizes

Tags: apache-spark, cluster-analysis, bigdata

What's the best way to achieve what follows:

(1)
My input data consists of three columns: Object, Category, Value. I need to cluster Objects based on Value but the clusters need to be Category specific i.e. I need a cluster for every Category. It's impractical to split a file and load category specific data individually.

Initially I thought it was simple (I was already able to cluster Objects for one specific Category) and loaded data into a pair RDD where the key was Category value. However, KMeans train method accepts RDD and I got stuck on trying to make RDD of the value for each key of original RDD.

(2)
Is there a method of clustering that returns optimal number of sets in the cluster except for starting with low K and iterating training while K increases until Within Set Sum of Squared Error stabilizes?

(3) 
Is there a method of clustering where the size of cluster sets could be controlled (the goal being producing more balanced sizes of sets)?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Why is it impractical to split your data set?

1. this will not take longer than a single k-means iteration (1 pass over the data set)
2. it will untangle the multiple problems you have, so some subsets can converge earlier, thus speed zp the overall process.

Note that k-means is best on multivariate data. On 1-dimensional data it is much more efficient to sort the data and then do kernel density estimation (or even simply *histograms* and have the user intuitively decide). Then you can easily do all thes "extras" such as ensuring a minimum cluster size etc.

Comment: Thank you Anony-Mousse for your answer and I apologize for the late reply.

Comment: If we just had a couple categories then we'd load the data for each category and cluster accordingly. We have hundreds categories and the set is changing. We do need to cluster individually for each category. I loaded all the data into a pair RDD where the key is the category. I got stuck on getting the values for each pair and passing them to KMeans.train as it expects RDD type. Could you recommend some source showing how Kernel density could be applied to clustering of one dimensional data? Thanks.

Comment: You could try using other tools inside each partition, such as ELKI. I tried Spark k-means, but it was many times slower. IIRC, ELKI also has a KDE based clustering. I have posted a Python code somewhere here to do this, too. But I don't have Scala code for this, and if I had it would likely require a RDD type, too.